# I accidentally disabled an extension, how can I find which one it was?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using CSS on Visual Studio Code and I got a message that gave me errors with an extension. Without thinking I disabled it but I realized that without that extension, if I press "f" for example, it no longer gives me the styles available with the letter F, (for example, font-size, font-style etc.). This applies to all available letters and styles.

I tried to install other CSS extensions, but no one can resolve this problem.

Comment: You can install extension `CSS IntelliSense` or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for all of your disabled extensions by searching [`@disabled`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_extensions-view-filters) in the extension manager.  After doing this, your extension list should be narrowed down enough for you to find the extension you disabled by accident so that you can enable it again.